# New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon repetition

Tags: powershell, triggers, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem with setting `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` cmdlet with parameter `-AtLogon`. In UI there is a option how often I want to repeat the action, and more other options what to set. But in PowerShell I don't have this parameters. How can I set this parameter in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` cmdlet with both `-AtStartup` & `-AtLogon` to create the trigger object. Then simply update the object with your required repetition values. In this example I have set the task to repeat every 5 minutes for and hour after logon.

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$trigger.RepetitionDuration = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1)
$trigger.RepetitionInterval = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)
$trigger | select *
```

Comment: On Windows 10 this unfortunately seems not working as it gives "The property 'RepetitionInterval' cannot be found on this object" error